# Authentication Message in TLS

Tags: tls, decryption, tls-intercept

I was reading [RFC8446-TLS13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4) and [a tls visualization](https://tls13.ulfheim.net) and could not grasp some concepts.

- I have all the tls connection data (client hello etc.) and SSL Logs (server_traffic_handshake_secret)
- I see that authentication message is all handshake messages - except the record headers- concatenated and hashed, but this does not give me the proper result

I can derive/expand secrets/keys from this information until some point.

I can not decrypt TLS13 connections because:

- I think I can't generate a proper Authentication Tag. And I did not understand how to generate one
- I don't exactly know how to 'decrypt' the encrypted data even if I have the key, iv, and authentication tag
- While I was using the same capture files and logs as the provided visualization link, my `SHA256` hashes are not the same as the link. I don't even think that is possible, since hashing is a mathematical procedure that would give the same output in same input.
- I am using `golang` as language and sniff all packets. I also log `SSLKEYLOGFILE` and have total control and my computer.

to put in a nutshell, i am trying to analyze tls connections on my computer

I am aware of wireshark, but I am doing this in a embedded programm and I don't want to import all wiresharks tools. that would be an overkill

Comment: Are you aware of wireshark tool? It is good tool to analyze and learn TLS from real connection

Comment: @RealTimeEngineer91 edited